# Layout with union and empty base class on Windows

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given the following program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct EmptyClass {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Storage {
 protected:
  union Union {
    T t;
    U u;
  } data;

  char flag = false;
};

class AnotherEmptyClass {};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Derived : private Storage<T, U>, public AnotherEmptyClass {};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Derived<char, EmptyClass>>);

int main() {
  printf("Storage<char, EmptyClass>: %zu\n", sizeof(Storage<char, EmptyClass>));
  printf("Derived<char, EmptyClass>: %zu\n", sizeof(Derived<char, EmptyClass>));

  printf("Storage<char, char>: %zu\n", sizeof(Storage<char, char>));
  printf("Derived<char, char>: %zu\n", sizeof(Derived<char, char>));
}
```

this outputs 2 2 2 2 on Linux, but 2 3 2 2 on Windows (both with clang and MSVC).

Why is that? It seems that using `EmptyClass` as a member of the union prevents empty-base class optimization on the derived class. But for a standard-layout type, empty base class optimization is required. Or is there a different reason for this layout?

Comment: clang on windows mimics msvc's layout for interop.  When did ebco become mandatory?  Maybe interop with older versions?

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo, it became mandatory with C++11 (which also introduced the notion of a standard-layout type, IIRC).

Comment: And I don't find anything under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nonstandard-behavior?view=msvc-160 that refers to this, or any /Zc option that would influence this behaviour: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-conformance?view=msvc-160

Comment: I am willing to say, a defect in MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class __declspec(empty_bases) Derived : private Storage<T, U>, public AnotherEmptyClass {};
```

Will do the job but I don't know, why this behavior is disabled by default for the Microsoft compiler, even for the 2019 version with latest framework and active conformance mode. Only a theory: This seems to be a long term issue and maybe the drawbacks of breaking functional code in a massive way were evaluated as not been reasonable.